How to get Swift IDE
I've been looking all over the internet for a Swift IDE download but could not find anything, could I get it on the apple website?
I thought it would be possible to download on GitHub but I could not find a single repository. I also could not find anything even related to it.

https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-on-windows/

There is no "swift IDE". If you want an ide to do swift in, you can use AppCode, Vs code or Swift playgrounds.
Realistically you should use Apple's official IDE called Xcode. You can download it from the Mac app store, the apple developer website or with the command below having command line tools installed.
xcode-select --install

Hope this helped !
